# There are three methods as below

Tags: java, methods, int, double, void

There are three methods as below.

`void method(double d, int i){}`

`void method(int i, double d){}`

`void method(String s1, String s2){}`

Now, if I call `method(0,0)`. Which method will be called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Java functions and determining which one to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519914/overloading-java-functions-and-determining-which-one-to-execute)

Comment: Have you tried to figure out which function will be called by compiling and running the code? If so what happened?

Answer (score 0):

It's a compilation error. The method method(double, int) is ambiguous. 
you need to have a method(int i, int j) for this or call like method(0,0.0) ;or method(0.0,0) or method("0","0");

Answer (score 0):

None!!
Java throws compile time error saying 'Ambiguous Method Call' cause java is unable to decide which method to call.

You have to do this to make the calls valid

```
method(0, 0d); // will call void method(int i, double d) 
.
method(0d, 0); // will call void method(double d, int i) 
.
```